# CGLayer from an IUView

Tags: iphone, uiview, ipad, cglayer

On iPhone or iPad someone know how we can get a CGLayer (not a CALayer) from an UIView?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried this, but I would do it like this:

1. Create the `CGLayer`
2. Get the layer's context by calling `CGLayerGetContext()`.
3. Draw the view to the layer's graphics context with `[view.layer renderInContext:]`.